# XStream: Deserialisation of a serialised java.sql.Time causes error

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization, xstream

The following code throws an exception, which I didn't expect at all!

```
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        java.sql.Time t1 = new java.sql.Time(now);
        String s1 = new XStream().toXML(t1);
        java.sql.Time t2 = (java.sql.Time) new XStream().fromXML(s1);
        if(!t1.equals(t2)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

[See XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/)

The question is, why, and is it a bug in XStream?

Comment: Do you mean that the last lines throws the IllegalArgumentException, or that some completely different exception is thrown somewhere?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you told us what the string in `s1` looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search gives that XStream uses this class to serialize java.sql.Time:
 http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/extended/SqlTimeConverter.html

Note the warning:

> Converts a java.sql.Time to text.
>    Warning: Any granularity smaller than seconds is lost.

So it's being truncated to an even second, and thus the comparison with the original (which has milliseconds) fails.

Comment: Super - thanks for that, and sorry I didn't make the question clearer.